# Facebook Embed video events?

Tags: javascript, facebook

is it possible to get events from Facebook video JavaScript api?
i couldn't find a way to do it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. Embedded video plugin only allows you to embed a Facebook video externally but not to interact with the video itself.